# React Native: Creating vertical ViewPagerAndroid

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to create a vertical ViewPagerAndroid on React Native, or is there a workaround for Android that ends up with a similar UI maybe using ScrollView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This currently isn't offered out of the box since ViewPagerAndroid implements only horizontal scrolling, and scroll snapping is implemented only on iOS. These are two approaches I would suggest exploring:

1. Give the illusion of a vertical pager by using the `transform` style property to rotate the ViewPagerAndroid by 90 degrees, and then `transform` each child 90 degrees in the other direction so their net rotation is zero. This is the approach we used in [InvertibleScrollView](https://github.com/exponentjs/react-native-invertible-scroll-view) and it works well for some use cases. You might find the same technique useful with ViewPagerAndroid.
2. Implement scroll snapping on Android. On iOS, React Native already offers an API for specifying how a ScrollView should snap at intermediate points, such as at the boundary of each page in a pager. On Android you could subclass ReactScrollView and implement the same behavior natively. This would require more work than rotating the pager, but is a more robust solution.

Comment: Now that pagingEnabled works for horizontal ScrollView on android, option 1 works quite well.